# Add an anchor to the redirect URL

Tags: views, 8

I have a website with some news. I create a view that shows them and filter  by category. When I use the filter, it reloads the page and goes at the top of the page. I want it doesn't move on the top of the page.

I added an anchor to the page, but I can't add it to the view redirect link. I tried implementing `hook_view_form_alter()` to add a custom submission handler, but it breaks the entire form and the news are not filtered.

I also looked at `hook_views_query_alter()`, but it doesn't seem it allow to do what I am trying to achieve.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: There is something similar asked for drupal 7 search results, I believe it can be used for Drupal 8 as well https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/260697/scroll-to-search-results-on-views-exposed-filter-submit-button/260700

Comment: The problem with that script is that it scroll to the content every time I go on the page, I want to scroll only when the page is refreshed by the filters form

Comment: With a little modification you can achieve what you want ;-)

Comment: Yes it works now I just add a condition to check if I have query éléments in my URL

Comment: I wrote up a simple solution below based on the D7 one.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple solution to scroll to top of the views results using jquery `scrollTop`

*THEMENAME/js/views-scroll-top.js*

```
(function ($, Drupal) {
  Drupal.behaviors.viewsScrollTop = {
    attach: function (context, settings) {
      //var scrollto = ".view-content"; // top of results
      var scrollto = ".view-filters"; // top of filters
      var url = window.location.href.split('?');
      if (url.length > 1 && $(scrollto).length) {
        $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $(scrollto).offset().top }, "slow");
      }
    }
  };
})(jQuery, Drupal);
```

*THEMENAME/THEMENAME.libraries.yml*

```
views-scroll-top:
  js:
    js/views-scroll-top.js: {}
```

*THEMENAME/THEMENAME.theme*

```
function THEMENAME_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
  // attach library only on specific view
  $route_name = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getRouteName();
  if ($route_name === "view.article.page_1") {
    $variables['#attached']['library'][] = 'THEMENAME/views-scroll-top';
  }
}
```

Change `THEMENAME` to your theme's name